# OpenAL listener orientation from pitch yaw And roll

Tags: java, opengl, audio, openal

I am making a game and currently ocupied with making my audio listener work. Ive done everything and i can even hear some sounds but the orientation of my camera (A defined class) isn't working along with my audio. Ive tried to implemend it myself by using this:

```
AL10.alListener3f(AL10.AL_ORIENTATION , cam.getPitch(),cam.getYaw(), cam.getRoll());
```

But that ofcource didn't work. What can i do to make my game work??

OpenGL version 2.0 and (OpenAl version 2.0 I think)
Thanks!

Edit:
From a answer ive managed to understand it needs to be in a float buffer. So this is how i create my cameras view matrix with the pitch and the yaw:

```
    viewMatrix.setIdentity();
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(pitch), rotateX, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(yaw), rotateZ, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
    Vector3f negativeCameraPos = new Vector3f(-position.x, -position.y, -position.z);
    Matrix4f.translate(negativeCameraPos, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
```

And the method i currently use for this isue:

```
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( 6 * 4);
    bb.order( ByteOrder.nativeOrder() );
    FloatBuffer listenerOrientation = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    listenerOrientation.put( 0, cam.getViewMatrix().m01 );
    listenerOrientation.put( 1, cam.getViewMatrix().m02 );
    listenerOrientation.put( 2, cam.getViewMatrix().m03 );
    listenerOrientation.put( 3, cam.getViewMatrix().m11 );
    listenerOrientation.put( 4, cam.getViewMatrix().m12 );
    listenerOrientation.put( 5, cam.getViewMatrix().m13 );

    AL10.alListener( AL10.AL_ORIENTATION, listenerOrientation );
    AL10.alListener3f(AL10.AL_POSITION, cam.getPosition().x, cam.getPosition().y, cam.getPosition().z);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate the view-vector and the up-vector from your pitch/yaw/roll representation. Most probably you already have that data since they are stored in the 2nd and 3rd row (or column) of the camera matrix.

Using this values, you can than call the `alListener(int pname, java.nio.FloatBuffer value)` method, with `pname = AL10.AL_ORIENTATION` and `value` containing the two vectors similar to this code sample:

```
listenerOrientation.put( 0, lookX );
listenerOrientation.put( 1, lookY );
listenerOrientation.put( 2, lookZ );
listenerOrientation.put( 3, upX );
listenerOrientation.put( 4, upY );
listenerOrientation.put( 5, upZ );

AL10.alListener( AL10.AL_ORIENTATION, listenerOrientation );
```

Source:
https://www.openal.org/documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf and http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=2631.0

Comment: Well maby it'll help to show you how i create my viewmatrix of the camera look at my edit